# Unresolved references exist in JBoss MetaData

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

I am getting following warning when starting Jboss 6.

WARN  [MappedReferenceMetaDataResolverDeployer] Unresolved references exist in JBossMetaData:
[myEJB.jar#GenDriver:MessageDestinationReferenceMetaData{name=queue/generator,type=javax.jms.Queue,link=null,ignore-dependecy=false,jndi-name=null,resolvoed-jndi-name=null,usage=null}]

ejb-jar.xml entries related to this are:

```
    <session>
            <ejb-name>GeneratorBean</ejb-name>
            <ejb-classgen.bean.GeneratorBean</ejb-class>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jms/JmsXA</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
            </resource-ref>
            <message-destination-ref>
                <message-destination-ref-name>queue/generator</message-destination-ref-name>
                <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            </message-destination-ref>
        </session>

<message-driven>
            <ejb-name>GenDriver</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>gen.bean.GenDriver</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>

            <activation-config>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>user</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>gen</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>password</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>gen</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>maxSession</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>1</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>dLQJNDIName</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>java:/queue/generatorDLQ</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>dLQUser</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>gen</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property>
                    <activation-config-property-name>dLQPassword</activation-config-property-name>
                    <activation-config-property-value>gen</activation-config-property-value>
                </activation-config-property>
            </activation-config>

            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jms/JmsXA</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
            </resource-ref>
<message-destination-ref>
                <message-destination-ref-name>queue/generator</message-destination-ref-name>
                <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            </message-destination-ref>
        </message-driven>
```

Anybody please suggest what is causing this warning?

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs when a Bean is using other bean which not deployed till. for example if you are having two beans A and B and you have provided ref of Bean B in Bean A. So when Jboss try to deploy Bean A it searches for Bean B and if Bean B is not found it shows this warning.
You can Ignore this warning. As when the deployment is complete and actual call to Bean A is placed it will again search for Bean B.